# Is it haram to buy a iPhone someone found?

Tags: halal-haram, theft

My friend wants to sell an iPhone to me. He claims he found it lost on a plane. My friend is non-Muslim and he used this phone for some time now he plans to sell it.

I am buying it from my friend with halal money, but since he is my friend, he told me the truth, that he actually found it 'lost' in a plane. He could choose to hide it, but since we are friends, he told me this fact.

Is it haram to buy the phone from him with money?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, it's not right to buy that phone (that **you know** is a lost phone).

If you didn't know the truth it would have been OK to buy it, but now that you know it's 100% wrong to buy it.

Comment: Is there any reason?

Comment: I would add to this, right now it's not right to buy the phone from him, but if your friend reported the lost phone and eventually became his after a certain period of time, then it's okay to buy the phone from him.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion do not buy it as your friend can return this mobile to the real person as the mobile phone will have contact numbers and sim in it, He did not try to return this, So it may also considered as theft.

Consider if your mobile lost somewhere and the person who found your mobile did not return to you saying he found it on the road I will not return it to you so what will you call that person.

Comment: why downvoted please add reason.